# Can this be solved analytically?

Tags: normal-distribution, exponential-function

I have a sum of two Gaussian type functions, $g_1(x) = C_1 Exp[-\alpha (X_1-x)^2]$ and $g_2(x) = C_2 Exp[-\beta (X_2-x)^2]$ and have found that the derivative w.r.t. $x$ is

$f(x) = 2 C_1 (X_1 - x) \alpha Exp[ -\alpha (X_2 - x)^2] + 2 C_2 (X_2 - x) \beta Exp[ -\beta (X_2 - x)^2]$

I would like to find where this function reaches a minimum and so I am trying to solve:

$C_1 (X_1 - x) \alpha Exp[ -\alpha (X_2 - x)^2] + C_2 (X_2 - x) \beta Exp[ -\beta (X_2 - x)^2] = 0$

for $x$. I thought this would be rather simple and just didn't want to work out the math by hand but Mathematica tells me that it cannot solve it. I thought this would be College Algebra level math involved here but it seems a bit more complicated than that now that I look at it. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for the minimum? As the Gaussian function has only a defined maximum? If it is then the distributions are not collocated then you will have two maximums defined by the scaling factor, if collocated then it is the sum of the scaling factors.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean, but I am positive there is a minimum because $C_1, C_2, \alpha, \beta$ are all greater than zero, and $X_1, X_2$ are not equal, so this function has two maxima and a minimum between $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: It has been a long day (but you are totally correct) as for finding that point it's the point at which the curves intersect? This solve $g(x_i) = f(x_i)$. Though I could be wrong again ;).